# PHP Google Drive Api - echo not working in if (!empty($_POST)) block

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to upload files in a folder called "Files" to google drive.
It uploads without any problem, but I want to echo a string to my html file after i click my submit button. (I want to print generated file id's.) But it doesnt print anything in this code block.
Please help!

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$file = new Google_DriveFile();
foreach ($files as $file_name) {
    $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
    $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
    $file->setTitle($file_name);
    $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
    $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
    $service->files->insert(
        $file,
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
            'mimeType' => $mime_type
        )
    );
    echo "file uploaded"; // This is not working!

}
finfo_close($finfo);
header('location:'.$url);exit;
```

}

Comment: header('location:'.$url);exit; causes it!

Comment: It doesn't print anything because after you print, you force the browser to another location, which cause the browser neglect the print and force you redirect first. If you want it to persist after redirect then use $_SESSION or just don't redirect the location using header.